# Call System output in Macro Variable

Tags: macros, sas, aix

I want to get the file size of a csv file in AIX and using following X and Call System Command to do. The problem is I cant get the "File Size" in a macro variable which I will be using later in the program.

```
data _null_;
    call system('du -g p_bhj_c_hh100uk01po1.csv');
    call symput('space','X du -g p_bhj_c_hh100uk01po1.csv');
    %put &space; 
run;


WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference SPACE not resolved.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the SYMPUT subroutine you call does not work like you are trying to use it (ala Perl).  I recommend reading the documentation on it.

The error you get on the SPACE macro is because it is inside the DATA Step.  Macros "write" SAS code for you, so it `&SPACE` macro is trying to be resolved BEFORE the DATA Step executes.

Here is a code example to do what you are looking for:

```
data _null_;
rc = filename("ref","e:\temp\reg.pdf");
fid = fopen("ref");
infonum = foptnum(fid);
do i=1 to infonum;
    infoname = foptname(fid,i);
    infoval=finfo(fid,infoname);
    put infoname= infoval=;
end;
close = fclose(fid);
run;

/*In Windows, attribute is "File Size (bytes)"*/
data _null_;
rc = filename("ref","e:\temp\reg.pdf");
fid = fopen("ref");
size=finfo(fid,"File Size (bytes)");
call symput("size",size);
close = fclose(fid);
run;
%put &size;
```

The File Size attribute may be different in AIX.  Run the first part to see all the attributes available.  Then modify the second accordingly.  Likewise, you will need to add the call to produce the file like you are already doing.

Comment: Thanks @DomPazz. It will surely work. Though I am getting an error "ERROR: Invalid DO loop control information, either the INITIAL or TO expression is missing or the BY expression is missing, zero, or invalid." while executing the first program.

Comment: add `put fid= infonum=;` in the first data step (before the do).  Sounds like it is failing to open the file.

Comment: Fortunately th second one worked like charm. Don't know why. Thanks again @DomPazz